# Why was the Saturn V several times as expensive as falcon heavy despite only having twice its payload?

Tags: rockets, cost, cost-to-orbit

Saturn V could lift 140 tons to low earth orbit, Falcon Heavy can lift 64 (expendable configuration). But Saturn V cost several times more per launch. Why?

Comment: Did you compare a price from about 1970 to another price from about 2020 with or without inflation adjustment?

Comment: Yes, approx 1 billion is in 2020 dollars

Comment: Recommend adding references to the two prices, in particular a lot of Saturn V numbers include the hardware on top, and Falcon heavy price should clarify if it is working fully expended. Ideally the two numbers would be the raw construction costs, rather than the R&D to develop, since Saturn V has a bigger starting R&D number but you could also claim Falcon Heavy is resting on a % of the entire US space program budget 1950 through 2010 so you can make the maths work which ever way you fancy.

Answer (score 11):

The Saturn V was the result of a crash program to put a man on the moon by the end of the decade, before the Soviets could do so. Cost was at best a minor consideration, in fact funding was deliberately spread around to gain political support. Additionally, it was developed in the 1960s, the Apollo program starting in 1961, and involved many new technologies that had to be developed first, such as the hydrogen-fueled upper stages and the large F-1 first stage engines. Many of the materials and manufacturing techniques used were new, some developed specifically for the Apollo program.

Falcon Heavy was designed from the start to be a commercially profitable launch vehicle based on the Falcon 9, by SpaceX, a company known for aggressively and successfully pursuing cost reductions. It deliberately used well-known, fairly mundane technologies: kerolox engines with a less-efficient but simpler gas generator cycle, and instead of composites or expensive milled and formed metal panels, it uses tanks formed from sheet metal reinforced with welded stringers.

In short, Saturn V was an early-generation launch vehicle that was never optimized for cost. Falcon Heavy took advantage of half a century of advances and minimizing operating cost was a major objective in its development.

Comment: In other words, the Saturn was rushed, and they were willing to pay any cost, while Falcon heavy was optimized to be cheap, and they took their time.

Answer (score 10):

There are several reasons.

1. The square-cube law. Amongst other things, this says that a mouse scaled up to elephant size would not be able to support its own weight. Larger objects need a greater amount of structural support, and this need for greater support is non-linear. The same applies to rockets. Lifting twice the mass to orbit requires a rocket that is more than twice as big.
2. The end goal. The primary purpose of the Saturn V rocket was to send a spacecraft to the Moon. Using the Saturn V to send something into LEO (which NASA did do with Skylab) represented an underuse of the rocket's capabilities.
3. Congress. One of the sideshow items that made (and still makes) NASA appealing to Congress is that NASA intentionally made (and still makes) their manufacturing spread across as many states as possible. Every state got to say that they were contributing to the Apollo space program, and every state received funding for this. SpaceX does not follow this wasteful paradigm.
4. We didn't know how to do it. A lot of the monies spent on the Apollo project involved learning how to build a rocket capable of sending humans to the Moon. We do know how to do it, now.
5. Advanced computers. The Saturn V used early 1960s computer equipment for its [Launch Vehicle Digital Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_Vehicle_Digital_Computer). It ran 12190 instructions per second, had 32,768 words of memory, and weighed 80 pounds. Modern vehicles can easily use late 1990s computer equipment, and if they're willing to fully bite the [Byzantine generals problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault) bullet, they can use even more modern computers. SpaceX appears to fully embraced the Byzantine generals problem and uses a lot of semi-modern computers, a lot more modern than late 1990s technology.
6. Advanced sensors. The Saturn V used a large and convoluted inertial platform for its accelerometers and angular measurements. Inertial measurement sensors have advanced a lot in the past 60 years. I'm not sure what SpaceX uses, but they certainly don't use an inertial platform, and they certainly don't use astronauts using a sextant for angular measurements.
7. Advanced manufacturing. 3D printing, for example, was decades in the future in the Apollo era. Now it is a decade or two in the past.
8. Reusability (or lack thereof). Nothing was reusable on the Saturn V. SpaceX designed the Falcon 9 from the start with reusability in mind.
9. Limited number of vehicles. SpaceX has built many more Falcon 9 rockets than NASA built Saturn V rockets. The first vehicle costs a lot (a whole lot) because of all of the research and development that went into the vehicle. The next one costs less than the first, and so on, and so on. When it's only a few vehicles (e.g., Saturn V, and now, SLS), that initial cost represents a huge portion of the overall budget.
10. GPS. GPS was initially invented to improve the accuracy of intercontinental missiles. The Saturn V would have benefited from GPS, but GPS didn't exist then. It does exist now, and it does make navigation easier (and more accurate).

I'm sure I've missed some reasons.

Comment: Your first point is wrong. The "tyranny" applies when you want to go twice as fast with the same payload. Lifting twice the payload requires a rocket twice as large.

Comment: More reasons: Building the Instrument Unit of the Saturn was much more expensive than the control computer of the Falcon Heavy. 1970 many low scale integration chips were used, 2020 only a few high scale chips. The Saturn used liquid hydrogen for second and third stage, Falcon Heavy rocket petrol. Tanks, plumbing, valves and engines for liquid hydrogen were much more expensive. The Saturn had 3 stages, Falcon Heavy only two, the extra stage needed much more money.

Comment: @RainerP. I know very little about orbital mechanics - mostly from playing kerbal space program and watching Scott Manley. But, I'm pretty sure that David's first point is correct.

Comment: @mgarey it is not, as the simple observation that you can launch twice the payload with two rockets will show. Their payload wouldn't suddenly plummet if you attached them side by side.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Thanks, that makes sense now that I think about it that way. [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/123290) explains that in more detail. That answer points out that in theory it is just a linear increase in size of rocket to size of payload, but in practice it doesn't quite work out that way - I'm guessing due to structural issues, needing more powerful engines that may also be less efficient, or probably many other issues.

Comment: @mgarey some factors favor larger rockets, others work against them. You can get closer to the theoretical ideal structures with larger rockets...a small rocket might theoretically only need very thin sheet metal tank walls, but in practice need thicker walls to make it practical to handle. Things like avionics don't scale with vehicle size. Things like tank insulation scale with *surface area* and larger vehicles are favored by the square-cube law. Welding thicker metal, and things like propellant slosh and distributing forces across a large structure might be more difficult.

Comment: The square-cube law also comes into play. It's possible to make a small(ish) rocket that is 95% propellant at launch. It is very hard to make a large rocket that is 85% propellant at launch. Saturn V and the Shuttle were up to 85% prop, and that was pushing it. And then the tyranny rules.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone, you are all right, but you have to account for something else, something which only one of you actually brought up. it can be summed up in one word.

**Reusability/expendability**

Saturn V's stages, after they were staged away, fell into the ocean with no plans to ever fire them ever again. Falcon heavy on the other hand, after it's boosters and first stage are used and fall away, land on a drone ship and are then used again. The cost to launch Saturn V also accounts for fuel, construction, and the actual cost to launch it. Falcon heavy's launch cost only accounts for fuel and launch costs. Not construction, because they can just use the thing again. although reusability isn't always the answer to cheaper launches, it certainly can make a difference if you're willing to go the distance. Oh yeah, and something else, please account for the fact that Saturn V (for missions apollo 11-17) needed to carry 4 separate spacecraft to the moon (the actual apollo spacecraft, the lander, the LES, and the return capsule). Therefore, making the amount of weight Saturn needs to carry a lot more than what FH needs to (lander, Capsule, the spacecraft itself, LES, and for some missions the rover.) while FH only needs to carry one thing (satellite)

Comment: The given payload mass for Falcon Heavy is the expendable configuration, and Falcon Heavy is still cheaper than the Saturn V in an expendible-to-expendible comparison.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff oh, I didn't consider that. Mostly because OP failed to mention whether or not FH was in expendable configuration.

Comment: The Saturn V carried four spacecraft: The launch escape system (which fortunately was never used for its intended purpose), the Moon lander vehicle, the Moon launch vehicle (which was carried by the Moon lander vehicle), and the Moon orbiter / Earth return vehicle. The Saturn V + Apollo was in a sense a seven stage rocket.

Comment: @DavidHammen will edit for that.

Answer (score 0):

As technology advances somethings become cheaper based on lessons learned and the development of the entire industry.

For example:

> The [Apple I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_I) went on sale in July 1976 at a price of US\$666.66.

> Customers can get [iPhone 14](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2022/09/apple-introduces-iphone-14-and-iphone-14-plus/) for \$33.29 (US) a month for 24 months or \$799 (US) before trade-in

Not only is the iphone a computer, but it is also a phone. Plus it has a ton of RAM, a faster CPU, and a monitor (the Apple I was just a board)

SpaceX didn't start from scratch. They took decades of advances to heart and then made their rockets more advanced. NASA in the Apollo era was focused on getting to the moon.

Also remember the timelines. Founding of SpaceX in 2002, it took 16 years to the first launch of the Falcon Heavy. NASA Launched the first Saturn V in 1967, less than 10 years after the first Successful launch of a US Satellite.